# I want Shiny UI with multiple inputs in a row

Tags: r, shiny

I want shiny sliderInput to be biuld like attached image[image]

side by side values i want like min and max. the input should be manual and not by slider or dropdown

I tried selectInput but its taking one value in a row I want two values in one row

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `fluidRow()` and `column()`. You start by using a `fluidRow()` and add `columns()` within that functions,...

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 3,
           selectInput("min", "Min Price", 1:4)
    ),
    column(width = 3, 
           selectInput("max", "Max Price", 1:4)
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 3,
           selectInput("min2", "Property type", letters[1:4])
    ),
    column(width = 3, 
           selectInput("max2", "Bedrooms", 1:4)
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output){ })
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. One more help needed, instead of dropdown can we input any value. without range. simple random input window

Comment: sure you can also replace `selectInput()` with `textInput()` or any other input,...

Answer (score 4):

@BigDataScientist has a great answer. You can also look into `splitLayout` in your UI. First you call splitLayout, define the desired cellWidths, then call the objects.

```
splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%", "50%"), selectInput(...), selectInput(...))
```